# json-tinyurl - more quota than is available

Tags: json, tinyurl

I am having some problems when I try to use json-tinyurl. When I am using [this](http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?url=http://simonwillison.net/)

I am getting this message: *foo({"ok": false, "error": "The API call urlfetch.Fetch() required more quota than is available."})*

There is also this message [here](http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?&callback=?): "*JSON (and JSON-P) wrapper around the [TinyURL API](http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/).*"

So my question is the following. What I just described means a) that because of a temporary problem (quota is unavailable) should I just wait for a while and the problem will be fixed or b) that I should move to TinyURl API that is proposed as "wrapper"?

Comment: Ok, problem seems to be fixed. Now, doing the same call doesn't return with quota problem.